# Elements are not aligning properly?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to build a portfolio website and having a bit of problems with How elements are aligned. I have one div for className to include top row elements side by side. they are not aligned very well. One image is on far left and one bottom and middle image is not centered. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. The python logo is at the bottom. The background is not meant to be black but i have it for better visualization.
 [image]

Js File:

```
export class ContentWrap extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="WholePage">
                <img id="apple" src={appleLogo}/>
                <img id="android" src={androidLogo}/>
                <img id="python" src={pythonLogo}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

CSS:

```
.WholePage{
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: black; 
}

#apple{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#android{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#python{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you are assigning individual styling to the images. Wouldn't it be much better to have them use the same styling, to provide congruency and consistency?

Anyways, your android id styling with all the autos is redundant.

Simply do the following:

```
.WholePage{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.WholePage-icons{
  width: 30%;
}

#apple{
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

#python{
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```